# How to send message to a group/channel from terminal using telegram-cli?

Tags: ubuntu, telegram

I can send message to a user using

```
telegram-cli 
msg UserName hello
```

But I can't do it with a channel/group. I get an exception -

> "FAIL: 38: can not parse arg #1 "

Is there way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried passing the Group/Channel ID instead of a username?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `telegram-cli`, you have to run `contact_list` to update chat list, then use `msg "@username" "Hello World"` (including quotation marks) to send message.

Comment: Also passing `user#00000` where `00000` is userID would work.